How to scale down a single landscape page from A4 to A5?
Motivation
I'm working on a document where the majority of the pages are A4 portrait. However, I need to include a single A5 landscape page. The catch is that when viewing the PDF on my computer, I want all pages to have the same width1 to avoid the hassle of zooming in and out or scrolling left and right, which many PDF viewers struggle with. Thus, I only want to achieve reading convenience without affecting the layout of the document when I print (where I will switch back to A4 landscape).
Requirements

Default pages are A4 portrait.
One single page is A5 landscape.
Text on the A5 landscape page should not appear rotated in PDF viewers.
Headers/footers (e.g., page numbers) should remain unrotated.
Content on the landscape page should be scaled down from A4 to A5 - so that layout/floatings remain consistent when I switch to print mode with A4 landscape.

Attempts so far
Here’s my best attempt using geometry and pdflscape, but it still results in an A4 landscape page rather than an A5 one.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is an A4 portrait page.

\afterpage{
  \newgeometry{paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=148.5mm, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm}
  \begin{landscape}
  \section{A5 Landscape Page}
  This page is in A5 landscape orientation.
  \end{landscape}
  \clearpage
  \restoregeometry
}

\clearpage
\section{Conclusion}
This is another A4 portrait page.

\end{document}

I’ve tried various combinations, but I can’t seem to get it right.
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

1 The short side of an A4 page equals the long page of an A5 page.

given that a landscape a5 is just a half filled a4, isn't the requirement just a normal page that is only half full? Perhaps I didn't understand the requirement

Does the PDF standard even allow documents to have differently specified page sizes between screen display and print? I know that it allows optional content groups, but I don't know if it is possible to have a page that presents itself as A5 on the screen and A4 to a printer.

Your attempt fails because \newgeometry does not allow changing paper sizes (it allows changing only margins.)

The long side of an A4 page equals the short page of an A5 page. This is false. The long side of an A5 page equals the short side of an A4 page. Hence @DavidCarlisle's comment above. It's also not clear why you say you're going to print A4 landscape, even though the default page size and orientation is A4 portrait. But whether the A4 is landscape or portrait, there is no need to scale A5 landscape down to fit. So it's really hard to guess what you're asking.

My interpretation of what the OP wants: What he has is a document that loads pdflscape, and hence one (or several) pages typeset in landscape mode using \begin{landscape}...\end{landscape}. What he wants a PDF document where every landscape page of the original is rescaled so that the width is equal to the width of the portrait page, so that previewing is easier on PDF viewers; but I assume he also wants the process to be simple to reverse so that he can just "turn off" this rescaling when preparing the document for printing.

I see several potential partial solutions: (a) just redefine \begin{landscape}...\end{landscape} and use \resizebox to scale the text body by sqrt(2). For previewing this will solve the problem of needing to scroll left and right. But will leave the page sizes at A4 landscape so you will see the extra white space, and headers and footers will be printed w.r.t. the A4 size. (b) Do a two-pass using pdfpages to scale all the landscape pages. (c) hack \shipout (not exactly sure how, but potentially can be done).

I apologize for the imprecise description. @WillieWong's interpretation was correct, the answer below is exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Assuming my interpretation of the question is correct, the following code would do the job. Since the desired output is just a rescaling of a certain page (or some pages) from A4 to A5, instead of changing the page size before typesetting (which would result in proportionally larger fonts), one should do the rescaling at \shipout. We accomplish this by taking advantage of atbegshi which intercepts the already-typeset page content, and scaling it using \resizebox from graphicx. But this only changes the page content and not the page size, so we complete it by setting manually the new \pdfpageheight and ..width (taking care that in \begin{landscape}...\end{landscape} these are "swapped") and computing the correct offset to place the rescaled box.
For your convenience I included a toggle that can turn off the rescaling and restore the landscape pages to A4; useful for printing.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{environ}  % To define the new `rotatedpage` environment
\usepackage{graphicx} % To rescale from A4 to A5
\usepackage{atbegshi} % To hack \shipout
\usepackage{lipsum}   % Dummy text (\lipsum); not needed for production

\newif\ifpreviewing
\previewingtrue  % Comment out this line to revert to standard behavior; restore landscape pages to A4

\makeatletter
\newbox\Thiede@saved@page
\NewEnviron{rotatedpage}{%
        \begin{landscape}%
                \ifpreviewing%
                        \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
                                \setbox\Thiede@saved@page=\hbox{\resizebox{!}{0.707\height}{\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}}
                                \setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\hbox{\box\Thiede@saved@page}
                                \pdfpageheight=210mm
                                \pdfpagewidth=148.5mm
                                \hoffset=-0.293in
                                \voffset=-0.293in
                        }%
                \fi%
                \BODY
        \end{landscape}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is an A4 portrait page.

\begin{rotatedpage}
\section{A5 Page}
This page is in A5 landscape orientation. \marginpar{test test test test test }\lipsum[1-2]
\end{rotatedpage}


\section{Conclusion}
This is another A4 portrait page.

\end{document}

The output as seen on my previewer


About the offsets: TeX for historical reasons sets the origin of a page at (1in,1in) measured from the top left corner of the page. If you scale the whole page by 1/sqrt(2), the correct origin should be (0.707in,0.707in) from the corner of the rescaled page. And 1-0.707 = 0.293.
